# mysql fulltextsearch handling short words

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I use the mysql fulltext search with ft_min_word_len = 3 in the moment.

This is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT title, MATCH(title) AGAINST('Apple Iphone 5') AS REL 
    FROM my_items
  ) AS items
WHERE REL > 0
ORDER BY REL 
DESC LIMIT 3
```

My test items in table:

```
apple iphone 4
apple MacBook MTB5543659
apple iphone 5
apple ipad
iphone 4 
iphone 5S
```

When I search e.g. "apple iphone 5" order by relevance Limit 4 I get following results:

```
apple iphone 4
apple iphone 5
apple MacBook MTB5543659
apple ipad
```

When I reduce ft_min_word_len to 1 I get, beside performance issues for bigger data, results a user would not expected:

```
apple iphone 5
apple iphone 4
apple MacBook MTB5543659    
apple ipad
```

**EDIT**

Tried Boolean Mode.

```
MATCH(title) AGAINST('Apple Iphone 5*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS REL
```

The result is

```
apple iphone 5
apple iphone 4
apple MacBook MTB5543659
iphone 5S
```

AND

```
MATCH(title) AGAINST('+Apple Iphone 5*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS REL
```

The result is

```
apple iphone 5
apple iphone 4
apple MacBook MTB5543659
apple ipad
```

So what can I do to get results like:

```
apple iphone 5
iphone 5s
```

I thought to give exact following words a higher relevance or calculating the relevance and doing some sortation but no idea how to do taht?

Reading other Threads with similar discussions did not really help.

Some other ideas?

Thx ruven

Answer (score 1):

Fulltext searches are supposed to be fuzzy. I think You might be able to
get the results you are asking for by using Boolean mode and a query string like
`'+iphone apple 5*'`, But You can probably see why it might not be very flexible.

Depending on your requirements I'm not sure it's wise to be to particular about 
what words you want back. Accept that you will get back some irrelevant results
and think more about which words are important.

-edit-

Aside from `+` you can control boolean searches with `<` and `>` as well to increase or
decrease relevance of a word. The results I get when playing around generally include
all iphones including the 4s, but not anything else.

Have you checked that the stopwords in addition to the min length? Try to increase or decrease the relevance of the numbers with `>` and see if that changes the relevance
you get in your query. If it doesn't then something is wrong.

-edit again-

Actually both '+iphone apple -4' and '+iphone apple +5*' works for me, forgot to restart
mysql. I realise this makes it inflexible, but I can't see how you could get your desired
level of control without being inflexible.

Comment: Thx, i edited my question above. But in your example you changed the searchstring. Using the same one you would not get iphone 5S in the results

Comment: So you seem to be more interested in the word iphone than apple, that's why i put the `+` there. The 5 is a bit tricky since it appears in MTB5... and isn't alone in 5s so i don't know how to handle that.

Comment: you are right, but the problem is, how do i know which word is of more importance? I search google how other companies handle this, but sadly i did not get any usable results.

Comment: In this case it seems you know since you can tell me which of the results should show up in the query. However, generally speaking there is no automatic way of deciding exactly what is relevant to your search. That is why I suggest that you are happy with a few false positives and just think a little bit about what you usually want to do with this query and try to optimize for that.

Comment: the problem is to filter results out, maybe ranking connected words higher than other, but in the moment I am stuck with that